# Implementing PFQueryTableViewController search function

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uisearchbar, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I need help setting up a PFQTVC search function. I have most of it complete but am stuck on how to switch the local data (self.tabledata) for the remote data (self.objects).  Here is my code. Im stuck on the filterContentForSearchText method.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResult;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"profs";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 500;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    self.tableData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Twenty-one"];
    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.objects count]];
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{

    PFQuery *query;


        query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];







    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    /*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
     query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
     }*/

    return query;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResult count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.objects count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];



    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[c] %@", YOUR_FIELD_TO_COMPARE, searchText];



self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}
```

`YOUR_FIELD_TO_COMPARE` is the field name for the value you are comparing in the search, e.g. `"name"`